# Is the following matrix notation correct for publication?

Tags: matrices, notation

I have been reading contradicting matrix notations regarding notating a matrix with subscript. Some say matrix should not stand with subscript but some books use this type of notation especially in case of partitioned matrices.

Is the following the correct matrix notation if I have a vector that stores n number of three dimensional matrices?

[image]

Comment: Most people would probably use tuples, e.g. $v = (P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n)$ where $P_i \in \mathbb{R}^{i \times j \times k}$, say. Making them boldface is fine if you want, though the more advanced the source the less decorated vectors and matrices become.

Comment: That clarifies the use of different formats for me, thank you!

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I have been trying to accept your answer (thank you) but there is no check mark next to your answer. I have flagged this issue for the moderator. Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: That's because @JoshuaP.Swanson didn't post an answer but just a comment. Note that depending on the journal with which you are publishing they may have their own notation guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Posting my comment as an answer to allow the question to get closed.)

Most people would probably use tuples, e.g. $v=(P_1, \ldots, P_n)$ where $P_i \in \mathbb{R}^{i \times j \times k}$, say. Making them boldface is fine if you want, though the more advanced the source the less decorated vectors and matrices become.

None of the journals I've published in have had guidelines for this.